# Using SQLiteQueryBuilder to generate an UPDATE query

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Is it possible to use [`SQLiteBuilder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html) to generate an `UPDATE` rather than `SELECT` query? I can't find anything about it in the docs, and it seems to be hardcoded in source code of this class, too:

```
public static String buildQueryString(
        boolean distinct, String tables, String[] columns, String where,
        String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit) {
    // [snip!]
    query.append("SELECT ");
```

Is there any around it?

If not, what is the best way to generate `UPDATE` queries without reinventing the wheel, then?

I do need raw SQL queries; I can't use an ORM.

Answer (score 1):

In the Android database API, "Query" refers only to SELECT statements.

If the values to be written are plain literal values, you can use [update()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29).
Otherwise, you have to use [execSQL()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[]%29).

Answer (score 0):

you can use [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

and call this method

> update(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)

Comment: This does not work for subqueries or for referring to old values.